# Geospatial data: weird longitude/latitude to the shapefile

Tags: r, geospatial

I am just getting started with geospatial data and have a question related to longitude/latitude. I downloaded the shapefile for the French departments (http://professionnels.ign.fr/geofla) and used R to read in the data:

```
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
map <- readOGR(dsn="...",layer="DEPARTEMENT")
map_f <- fortify(map)
head(map_f)
```

If I look at the longitude-latitude, it are numbers like long = 885661.8, lat = 6679942. In contrast, the long-lat combination for Paris is 2.352222, 48.85661 (`geocode("Paris")`). So I don't really get why the numbers are so different in magnitude? Can somebody help me or give some good references?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to So! Please provide a reproducible example, the link you provided is a website in french, why dont you post the actual link to the shapefile...

Comment: Thank you for your response. This link should do it: https://wxs-telechargement.ign.fr/oikr5jryiph0iwhw36053ptm/telechargement/inspire/GEOFLA_THEME-DEPARTEMENTS_2015_2$GEOFLA_2-1_DEPARTEMENT_SHP_UTM20W84MART_D972_2015-12-01/file/GEOFLA_2-1_DEPARTEMENT_SHP_UTM20W84MART_D972_2015-12-01.7z . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Whatever link you posted is requiring me to accept some certification/verification im not willing to do, try saving the shapefile to dropbox and post the dropbox link...Short of that, I doubt you'll get help on SO by providing sketchy links...

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian is correct, we do ask for reproducible examples in the R tag. Having said that, they generally don't like dropbox links because they break so often, but anything is better than nothing I suppose. I didn't get a certification request with that link but it did give me a compressed file, those being high risk of malware.

Comment: Longitude measurements range from 0° to (+/–)180°. Lat is 0 to +/- 90. So the one that was 885661 is either being read incorrectly or needs some transformation applied to it (or is just wrong).

Comment: This is the official link: https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/geofla-departements-30383060/ . You can then click on the first one that has SHP in the green box. 'Télécharger' means download. It is an official site from the government.

Comment: Again, as @Hack-R mentioned, you're not going to get any help posting compressed files. Hack-R is also right that links like dropbox are frowned upon but in this circumstance its better than downloading a compressed file.

Comment: The lat/long aren't weird, they are simply projected. Can you provide the output for `map_f` so we can see the projection that is assigned to the data. Likely you will simply need to reproject to achieved familiar lat/longs. A good reference is [the difference between projected and geographic coordinate systems](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/89b720a5-7339-44b0-8b58-0f5bf2843393.htm).

Comment: Hello, that command gives me : "+proj=utm +zone=20 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" . I'm not to sure what all of this means, so I think I've got some reading to do

Comment: Are you sure the data are from France? [Zone 20](https://epsg.io/32620) covers part of Canada and some parts of South America (with some French territories).

Answer (score 3):

The coordinates look projected (perhaps UTM) and not lat,long. I think that the fields are just mislabeled. I do not read French but in quick scan of the site you linked this caught my eye:

En métropole : (RGF 93) projection Lambert93

En outre-mer : (système légal)- Projections UTM

Neither of which are geographic coordinate systems. Please track down the metadata and check the coordinate system. You can also check `proj4string(map)` to see it there is a coordinate system defined.

Comment: Hello, that command gives me : "+proj=utm +zone=20 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" . I'm not to sure what all of this means, so I think I've got some reading to do

Comment: Your data is in a projected coordinate system: Universal Transverse Mercator, Zone 20 and the WGS84 datum. The coordinate units are in meters representing easting and northing.

Comment: Try ``spTransform(map, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))``